# Unity RTS Movement

Tags: c#, unity

I am trying Unity out and I want to try and write an RTS. What would be the best way to go about getting the basic, right click to set a destination working within Unity? I know how to get the `mousePosistion Vector3`, but past that not much. Please show some code examples if you can, it would help much more than just telling how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

When just starting out it's useful to see an example. See [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/17634-C-amp-C-style-RTS-Community-Project-Generals) for an example RTS game in Unity. From that project you should be able to answer a good number of your own questions regarding how to get started with RTS development in Unity.